# performance metrics for typescript methods

Tags: typescript, metrics

I have a framework written in typescript. These have a lot of methods which rely on browser opening and performing some action. I want to capture latency metrics for each of them. I have thought of the following 2 ways till now-

Method -1 :

```
export const startSession = async function (): Promise<void> {
    const startTime = Date.now()
    //Method performs some actions.
    const endTime = Date.now()

    const executionTimeMs = endTime - startTime
    const performanceLog: performanceMetrics = {
        apiName: "startSession",
        executionTime: executionTimeMs
    }
    publishMetrics(performanceLog)
}
```

We will have to update all methods with these calls if we choose this method. The other method looks like this -

Method-2

```
export const startSession = withPermanceLogging(async function (): Promise<void> {
    //Method performs some actions.
})
function withPermanceLogging<F extends (...args: any) => any>(fn: F): F {
    return (async (...args: Parameters<F>) => {
        const startTime = Date.now() 
        const ret = await fn(...args as any)

        const endTime = Date.now()
        const executionTimeMs = endTime - startTime
        const performanceLog: performanceMetrics = {
            apiName: fn.name,
            executionTime: executionTimeMs
        }
        publishMetrics(performanceLog) 

        return ret
    }) as F
}
```

This method won't work in case of callbacks/.then

Are there any other options available to capture metrics for methods?